# Apache URL rewrite to a dynamic URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

my PHP website uses dynamic URL's and runs in Apache. This website can be viewed in Dutch and English.
Default is dutch but I want people to see the English version by default if they visit: http://example.com
The English version can be viewed with http://example.com/en but this is a dynamic URL and the /en directory is not physical present. I can do a 301 redirect but I don't want users to see /en in the URL.

This is what I have so far in my virtualhost config:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /en [NC]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work at all. I still get to see the Dutch page when visiting the .com domain.
Does anyone know the right rewriterule to achieve my goal? I prefer the rule in my apache virtualhost config file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try someting lke:

```
RewriteRule !^[a-z]{2}/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I hope it works for you

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately the rule you provided results in an infinite redirect loop to /en/en/en/en etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html which details all the possible flags. Since you say /en is not physically present, you might need to use P or PT so your other rules get evaluated after the rewriting.

You might want to try keeping the original URI as part of the redirection.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /en/$1 [NC]
```